# HTML, PHP form submit and then redirect error

Tags: php, form-submit, redirect

I don't know what i'm doing wrong... I want to submit a php form and then I want to redirect to another page outside my url. This is my code, I'm a beginner in this, so any help is very appreciated.

Code:

```
<?php   
if(empty($_POST['fname1']) && strlen($_POST['fname1']) == 0 || empty($_POST['lname1']) && strlen($_POST['lname1']) == 0 || empty($_POST['email1']) && strlen($_POST['email1']) == 0 || empty($_POST['address1']) && strlen($_POST['address1']) == 0 || empty($_POST['city1']) && strlen($_POST['city1']) == 0 || empty($_POST['cel1']) && strlen($_POST['cel1']) == 0)
{
    return false;
}

$fname1 = $_POST['fname1'];
$lname1 = $_POST['lname1'];
$email1 = $_POST['email1'];
$address1 = $_POST['address1'];
$city1 = $_POST['city1'];
$cel1 = $_POST['cel1'];
$veg_24176 = $_POST['veg_24176'];
$soy_24176 = $_POST['soy_24176'];
$glu_24176 = $_POST['glu_24176'];
$lac_24176 = $_POST['lac_24176'];
$chili_24176 = $_POST['chili_24176'];
$nuts_24176 = $_POST['nuts_24176'];
$choco_24176 = $_POST['choco_24176'];
$comments1 = $_POST['comments1'];

$to = 'hola@chipzcolombia.com'; // Email submissions are sent to this email

// Create email 
$email_subject = "Message from NUEVA.";
$email_body = "You have received a new message. \n\n".
              "Fname1: $fname1 \nLname1: $lname1 \nEmail1: $email1 \nAddress1: $address1 \nCity1: $city1 \nCel1: $cel1 \nVeg_24176: $veg_24176 \nSoy_24176: $soy_24176 \nGlu_24176: $glu_24176 \nLac_24176: $lac_24176 \nChili_24176: $chili_24176 \nNuts_24176: $nuts_24176 \nChoco_24176: $choco_24176 \nComments1: $comments1 \n";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n";  
$headers .= "From: contact@chipzcolombia.com\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email1";    

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers); 
return true;// Post message
ob_start();
exit(header("Location: http://example.com/thankyou.html"));



?>
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @bfontaine the code is locked in the edit-pipeline

Comment: get rid of the `return true`!

Comment: Why are you checking string lengths when the empty check is already passed? I don't think you need 2 checks for each field. Also, anything written after return true will never execute therefore that should be your last line.

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to head in section attacks via the `email1` field, probably others too. It helps to use an email library to avoid problems like that.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of doing this is :

```
if(mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers)){
    header("Location: http://example.com/thankyou.html");
    exit();
}else{
   return false;
}
```